# Which AMD CPUs have built-in TPM, equivalent to Intel's TXT?

Tags: cpu

The newer Intel CPUs with TXT function have a built in TPM,
Is there any equivalent function in AMD?

Comment: Not sure this was downvoted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that AMD's use  ["Trustzone"](http://www.amd.com/en-us/press-releases/Pages/amd-strengthens-security-2012jun13.aspx) is broadly equivalent (but I understand "trustzone" goes further then TXT)

Comment: Trustzone seems to be on ARM only, are there any X86 version?

Comment: As per my link, Trust one embeds an ARM core for control of an x86 processor.